# Xamarin forms warning

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

It is showing failed to load 'C:\User\name\source\repos\App4\App4\App4\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\App4.dll'.
Check the file exist or project has been built

What can I do to correct the warning?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question could use a little more detail, you may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem building your solution.

Try to clean bin/obj folders, restart VS and then make a rebuild. Check for errors in the output console.